# Export WMS layer with all (even scale-dependent) features

Tags: qgis, wms, export, pdf, layout-manager

I've got this problem:

1. I have added a WMS layer to my QGIS map.
2. The WMS layer contains scale-dependent features. Some features disappear as I zoom in, and some disappear as I zoom out.
3. I'd like to export a PDF with all features through the layout manager at a specific scale (even those features not shown at this scale).
4. Is there a workaround for this?

An example:

1. I added a WMS layer that includes parcels, but the parcels are shown only if the scale is above 1:2000. If the scale is 1:50.000 (which is my preference), the parcels are not shown. I'd like to export a PDF at the scale of 1:50.000, even with the parcels.

Comment: That's not how WMS works, you get a picture of the data not the data. Maybe you need a WFS

Comment: If the server admin has set it so that the features in the map don't show at a certain scales then there is nothing you can do about it. This has nothing to do with the client you are using (QGIS).

Answer (score 0):

If all your WMS features are on one WMS layer you are out of luck... you can play with the export resolution (DPI), but you will never see all features in the PDF.

If you have multiple layers in your WMS service, i.e. a separate layer for the parcels, you could use [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org) to build a WMTS service with your WMS layer as source. When you load the MapProxy WMTS layer into QGIS, you can limit the display to a certain tile level. But be warned that it is not so easy to get the WMS labels perfect.